# How can I add HTML code with notepad without installing an IDE

Tags: html

I am a starter in programming. One of my friends told me that I can start programing without installing any app and that I need only notepad to start learning HTML. The thing I can't find out is how I actually make it work. I inputted the code he gave me and I also made sure there where no typos, but then after I saved it I can not open it as a local file. I have only been able to open it as a text document so I can only see the code.

Comment: when you save the file ensure the option that says "save as type" is set to all
after this you can name your file anything but use the .html extension
eg. index.html

Comment: Also, just start with an online course (e.g. https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html) so you don't even have to do the saving thing :P.

Comment: You can write every program with Notepad. Notepad doesn't offer the terminal or extensions that let you execute programs easily like in IDE(s). Also, notepad doesn't offer snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to save the file you are working on with the extension: `.html`. Then you have to open it with a browser, and you will see there the content of it

Comment: Thank you very much it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can create a notepad and save it as name.html (not as .txt)
write the code inside it.

Comment: Thank you very much it solved the problem

Comment: @RithvikRavikumar https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the notepad software. Unfortunately, this is not the best option. In fact, specialized software is recommended. Thanks to them, you will be able to write code faster thanks to the suggestions made by the software or to the very useful shortcuts! If you want to use this software, I recommend you one of the best on the market: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

If however you want to stay with notepad, you just have to click on "File" > "Save as" and to choose the type of file you want. In your case, it will be .html (Hypertext Markup Language)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called [filename].html, and right click on it to open it in notepad. After Editing the file and adding your code to it, you can double click on it and it will open in your browser.

If you start enjoying to code, getting an IDE will make it much better. Visual Studio Code is recommended for this as it is user friendly and won't take up much storage space :)

[code.visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0):

After saving the HTML code save it as filename.html, make sure that file extension is .html otherwise the filesystem will not recognized it.

Then right click on the file and open it with chrome or whatever browser you have and it will work, else open browser and drag it to browser and drop it, your html page will open in browser.